# Praying mantis identification

Tags: species-identification, entomology, taxonomy

I found this praying mantis in Bangalore, India. It is around 6 cms in length and has a distinct marking on the forelimbs. Can I know the species ?

[image: This is the best photo i could get]

[image: Here's another angle]

Comment: @charles, There's another angle. I'm pretty sure it is a mantis and in fact according to a taxonomical key that I found, I think it may belong to the genus 'Hestiasula' . I'm just waiting for a specific confirmation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> .. according to a taxonomical key that I found, I think it may belong to the genus 'Hestiasula'.

You're absolutely correct! This is of the species *[Hestiasula brunneriana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hestiasula_brunneriana)*, and is belongs to a group of praying mantis that are referred to as "[Boxer mantises](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxer_mantis)", due to their enlarged raptorial forelegs, of which are used for communication.

And though I can't quite tell, but at first glance this appears to be a female, due to what seems to be a longer than not abdomen; a female will only have 6 segments, whereas a male will have 8, however, the segments belonging to the female will be longer than that of the males. If you can somehow get an underbelly image, a much more definitive statement can be made.

The following image accurately matches your aerial image:

[image]

And then here's an image that demonstrates those distinct black markings on the raptorial forelegs:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @charles . Could you please upload the link to the key that you found. I would find it pretty useful for future reference. Thanks again.

Comment: @AdDate I used [this](http://www.nbair.res.in/insectpests/imageindex.php?keyword=A) image index, provided by the Indian Council of Agricultural Research, which is accompanied with taxonomic details.